# Unable to compile with IAR arm compiler when building with scons ... License check failed

Tags: c++, compilation, arm, scons, iar

I am able to point to the iccarm compiler, but receive following error:

> Fatal error[LMS001]: License check failed. Use the IAR License Manager

I have

1. Included the external os path

   `"env = Environment(platform='cygwin',ENV={'PATH': os.environ['PATH']})"`
2. Also specifically included path for compiler in CPPPATH.
3. Did also try with an evaluation version of ARM compiler

Could anybody Please let me know what is the missing link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including, or better: propagating, the PATH variable might not be enough. The compiler in question is obviously using additional environment variables to find its license files...assuming that you have a license indeed and compiling works fine in a standard shell.

Try including the whole shell environment with:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
```

and see if this makes things work.
If not, please post your current SConstruct.

Regarding your comment about 2., the CPPPATH variable is for paths that should get scanned for header files (implicit dependencies via #include statements)...so it shouldn't have anything to do with your problem. Anyway, please check the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ) and the MAN page for the proper usage of these simple constructs.

Comment: env = Environment(ENV = os.environ) did the job for me ... also thanks for the MAN page .. i was stuck with the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by setting:

```
env['ENV']['SYSTEMDRIVE'] = ['C:']
```

which is equivalent to:

```
export SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
```